# systemd style to keep the process running status out of sync

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, systemd

Currently I am facing an issue with below as my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=XYZ Service
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
TimeoutStartSec=900
Type=simple
KillMode=process
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/xyz/run.sh start'
ExecReload=/bin/bash -lc '/xyz/run.sh autorecover'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -lc '/xyz/run.sh restart'
PIDFile=/xyz/bin/dgs.pid
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=60s
RestartSec=45s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I do
service xyz start  --> it goes and executes the start function but when I do
service xyz status --> it still shows activating.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour happens when the systemd service manager is still waiting for the process to start. I normally see this when:

- `ExecStartPre=` hangs
- `Type=notify` is present but `ExecStart=` doesn't call sd-notify

I don't normally use `PIDFile=`, but it's typically used with `Type=forking` while you are using `Type=simple`.  This is what makes me suspect `PIDFile=`.

`man systemd.service` says this about `PIDFile`:

> The service manager will read the PID of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service.

I couldn't reproduce the problem with a missing PIDFile, but I still suspect the systemd service manager is waiting for `PIDFile=` to be populated with the PID of the main process before it considers the unit as `activated`.  If your service is complicated, then systemd might have some problems figuring out which PID to track. It could be that this `Type=simple` process isn't writing its PID to this file.

Comment: I tried with other types as well but this same issue occurs with other.
I will try with the PID stuff you mentioned.